# Windows Server 2016 - VPN timout on certain websites

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2016, timeout, pptp

First of all: I'm quite unexperienced with windows server and vpn so be patient and just tell me if I'm lacking important informations.

**Expected setup:**
I've got a Strato-Server (Windows Server 2016) and some client computers. I want the client computers to be connected via VPN through that server and still be able to surfe on websites.

**Current setup:**

- I've added the RemoteAccess (Direct Access and VPN) role
- I've started the Network-Policy-Server and set it up as "RAS-Server"
- I gave two user-accounts the permission to connect.
- In Windows 10 I've created a new VPN-Connection
- (VPN Adapter) I've set the ipv4 settings to **not** use the standard-gateway of the remote-network
- I logged in with one of the accounts via PPTP

**Current state / problem:**
Closely every website is working while being connected to the vpn except 2-3 pages (so far).
One of them is `http://www.apotheken-umschau.de` (noticed its not using SSL).

**What I've tried:**
This is where my knowledge lacks too hard.

- I disabled the firewall of the client and server - no success
- I tried another website without SSL (http://www.sonnenseite.com) - works
- I tried to access `http://www.apotheken-umschau.de` without the vpn - works
- I tried to access `http://www.apotheken-umschau.de` directly from the server (RDP) - works
- I traced the request via `tracert apotheken-umschau.de` - reaches the server and then gets a timeout

```
Routenverfolgung zu apotheken-umschau.de [81.17.211.65] über maximal
30 Hops:  
1    18 ms    18 ms    18 ms  equi-score.com [81.169.xxx.xx] // Thats my server
2    *        *        *      Timeout.
```

---

I can see the request is reaching my windows-server but its not going anywhere else. Further I've got no ideas what could cause it.

If I can provide any additional informations please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after searching for hours I've found the problem. In case this is too dumb and you guys think this answer wont help anyone, just comment/flag and I'll delete this question entierly.

**Problem:**
After connecting to the vpn a new route got added with destination `81.0.0.0` and gateway with the servers ip. The website however also has an IP that starts with `81.x.x.x` so that traffic got tunnled through the vpn which is not intended to be.

After deleting the route the website shows up.